# putting delete restriction with commander builder

Tags: c#, sql

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da = new OracleDataAdapter("select userid, firstname, lastname, salary, location from test_dummy", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            cmdbld = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.Columns["userid"].ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns["userid"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.Columns["userid"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Update?",
                "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Columns["location"] == null)
                    try
                    {
                        da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
                        MessageBox.Show("Data updated");
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                        button1_Click(sender, e);
                    }
                if (dataGridView1.Columns["location"] != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You can not update this line due to location filled");
                        button1_Click(sender, e);
                    }
        }

            if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No change has been made.");
                button1_Click(sender, e);
            }
    }
```

this is the code. How do I put a restriction on row so that row with location can't be deleted but can be updated? I put read only so location can't be updated but it won't prevent it from getting deleted. Yes, I know I can decide not to use commander builder to make things more flexible but if I do that, I lose freedom of editing multiple rows at once. Help please.

Comment: [visual-studio tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info)

Comment: @Shin where from rows deleting, as I can't see code for delete.